# SearchView is not collapsed in new fragment with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am working with a simple activity having two fragments. Both fragments have searchView as menu item. The problem is if I expand searchview in first fragment, its expanded in the second fragment and vice versa; which I do not want.

The fragments are,

```
class TitleScreen : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title_screen, container, false)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.play_btn).setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_title_screen_to_register)
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}

class Register : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.signup_btn).setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_register_to_match)
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
}
```

The menu is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24px"
        android:title="search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Navigation is,

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            app:startDestination="@+id/title_screen">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/title_screen"
            android:name="com.example.android.navigationsample.TitleScreen"
            android:label="fragment_title_screen"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title_screen">
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_title_screen_to_register"
                app:destination="@id/register"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:name="com.example.android.navigationsample.Register"
            android:label="fragment_register"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register"/>
</navigation>
```

How can I keep the menu collapsed in the next fragment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different `android:id`. The Menu system has no idea which Fragments are giving which `MenuItem`, so all it sees is the same MenuItem and therefore correctly keeps its state. Using a different `android:id` for a different fragment means that the Menu treats them as separate menu items with separate collapsed/expanded state.

Comment: Can you give an example? How do I set a different id for each MenuItem?

Comment: @Rondev - use a different `android:id`

Comment: Are you saying I have to create a different search menu xml file for each fragment? Can't I just change it programmatically in onCreateOptionsMenu() ?

Comment: @Rondev - anything that gives you a different ID would work, yes.

Comment: I set a different itemId to each MenuItem using `ViewCompat.generateViewId()` but each time I am navigating back to the fragment with SearchView it gets cleared out automatically because somehow onQueryTextChange is triggered automatically.
Is there any fix for this? I'm kinda struggling on this one

Comment: @Rondev - if you're using `generateViewId()`, that means you're getting a unique ID every time `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is being called (i.e., a brand new ID == a new instance of SearchView), so yeah, none of the state associated with your old ID will be restored to your new ID. It has to be a consistent, unique ID if you want that.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the ids to 2 different large integers and it still remains as I described in my previous comment :(